# Twitter bootstrap carousel with pictures that are not uniform

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Let me start with i am sorry for the long post.
I'm attempting to use the bootstrap carousel and unfortunately the pictures i have been given are NOT uniform.  for example some are 100x200, doe are 150x100, etc.  The aspect ratios are different, letter vs landscape.  Ive attempted a number of things, including the using the following helper function on load of each of my images in the Carousel:

```
function ScaleImage(srcwidth, srcheight, targetwidth, targetheight, fLetterBox) {

    var result = { width: 0, height: 0, fScaleToTargetWidth: true };

    if ((srcwidth <= 0) || (srcheight <= 0) || (targetwidth <= 0) || (targetheight <= 0)) {
        return result;
    }

    // scale to the target width
    var scaleX1 = targetwidth;
    var scaleY1 = (srcheight * targetwidth) / srcwidth;

    // scale to the target height
    var scaleX2 = (srcwidth * targetheight) / srcheight;
    var scaleY2 = targetheight;

    // now figure out which one we should use
    var fScaleOnWidth = (scaleX2 > targetwidth);
    if (fScaleOnWidth) {
        fScaleOnWidth = fLetterBox;
    }
    else {
       fScaleOnWidth = !fLetterBox;
    }

    if (fScaleOnWidth) {
        result.width = Math.floor(scaleX1);
        result.height = Math.floor(scaleY1);
        result.fScaleToTargetWidth = true;
    }
    else {
        result.width = Math.floor(scaleX2);
        result.height = Math.floor(scaleY2);
        result.fScaleToTargetWidth = false;
    }
    result.targetleft = Math.floor((targetwidth - result.width) / 2);
    result.targettop = Math.floor((targetheight - result.height) / 2);

    return result;
}

function OnImageLoad(evt) {

        var img = evt.currentTarget;

        // what's the size of this image and it's parent
        var w = $(img).prop('naturalWidth');
        var h = $(img).prop('naturalHeight');
        //var tw = $(img).parent().width();
        //var th = $(img).parent().height();
        var tw = $(img).parent().parent().parent().parent().width();
        var th = $(img).parent().parent().parent().parent().height();
        // compute the new size and offsets
        var result = ScaleImage(w, h, tw, th, true);

        // adjust the image coordinates and size
        img.width = result.width;
        img.height = result.height;
        $(img).css("left", result.targetleft);
        $(img).css("top", result.targettop);

}
```

and using the following for each of my images for the carousel

```
<img src="~/Images/Img1_Tall.jpg" alt="Tall" id="firstImage" onload="OnImageLoad(event);" />
```

and for the FIRST image in the carousel it works great, but each one after that they seem to just end up their natural size and are horizontally centered but are just against the top boarder of the carousel.

I've even changed the "onload" to pass the values of the length and width of the image but that didn't work either, in debug it seems only the first image kicks off the "onload" event.

the effect i am going for is if the ratio of the container is 3:4 and the ratio of the image is 1:2, the image stretch to meet the left and right edges and would center vertically and have letter box above and below, but the container does not change so that the navigation buttons of the carousel do not move. if the image is 2:1, the image would stretch to meet the top and bottom centered horizontally with letterboxes on the right and left, again keeping the navigation buttons unmoved.

any help would be appreciated... including:

> > what you are trying to do is crazy

Answer (score 1):

do you want to do something like http://jsbin.com/zotelasa/1 . With that code I can get the active items w,h or any other variables you used in your code to run scale image. Because of parent.parent codes it applies to carousels main divs but you can set your own container.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution would be to resize the images using an image editor, and save the properly-sized images to a folder named eg carousel_images. Then whenever you get new content you simply run the image through your editor. With a carousel you're most likely dealing with a number of images in the several to dozens range and not hundreds or thousands.

A more complicated solution is explain to your image provider that you need everything one size. The images aren't going to look right if you're stretching and skewing them on the fly, and you can show them an image with the aspect ratios wrong to explain what you mean.

Finally, as a technical solution, I would try to find out why your image resizer is only being run on the first image. From the sound of it, other images just aren't being run through your function. I think that the technical solution should be a last resort in this case because, like I said, the end results are just not going to be as good. You should at a minimum, if possible, handle each image by hand to make sure the result is adequate.

Answer (score 0):

**...And** the answer is a little long too...

• I assume that the width’s image’s parent is a constant, and while you don’t change the width’s viewport that must remain.

**A-.** Get the width’s image’s parent…
(Because the id attribute I took the grand parent’s parameter, that is (must be) the same than the parent’s one).

**B-.** With the below value deduce the height’s image’s parent, including the preferred ratio (in this case 16x9…

**C-.** … And with this, set the images’ parents height collection (all the elements with class=”item”).

**D-.** In order to conserve your carousel’s responsive characteristic, you must add the $F_getAdjustImagesParents function to the window resize event.

**E-.** Set the slide’s images position to absolute (Note: That must be via JQuery because if you do it in Css the bootstrap carousel will not display correctly. I did it with a new class for the images ('myCarouselImgs').

**• Bootstrap carousel’s event 'slide.bs.carousel' and 'slid.bs.carousel'.**

As you know, after the ‘click’ event, the slide.bs.carousel event is one of the firsts events that imply the change from the present slide to the next one; while the 'slid.bs.carousel' one is the end of the process.

**F-.** In the first one (slide.bs.carousel event), using the ‘relatedTarget’ variable of the Bootstrap’s plugin, the item’s id attribute and a item’s data attribute, get the number of the next item (ensure that these last ones -id attribute and data attribute- be present).

**G-.** In the second one, 'slid.bs.carousel', get the image’s size. For that you need to identify the implied image. I gave an id to each one. With this and the value obtained in previus step, it can do it.

**H-.** Well, now you already have the four values required for the ScaleImage function.  You can call it…

**I-.** … And apply the result with some effect

```
    var $parentImgW = ' '
    var $parentImgH = ' ';
    var $myCarousel = $('#myCarousel')
    var $carouseItems =  $('.item');
    function $F_getAdjustImagesParents(){
       $parentImgW = $myCarousel.width(); // A
       $parentImgH =  ($parentImgW*9)/16; // B
       $carouseItems.height($parentImgH+'px').css('max-height',$parentImgH+'px'); //C
       console.log('$parentImgW ====> '+$parentImgW);
       console.log('$parentImgH ====> '+$parentImgH)
    };
   $F_getAdjustImagesParents();

   $(window).on('resize',function(){  // D
        $F_getAdjustImagesParents();
   });

   $('.myCarouselImgs').css('position','absolute'); // E


   $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {// The slide’s change process starts
       var $slideNum = $("#"+event.relatedTarget.id).data('slide_num'); // F
       console.log('$lideNum ====> '+$slideNum)
       $myCarousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function(event) {//The slide’s change process ends
          var $imgW = $('#myCarouselSlideImage'+$slideNum).width(); //G
          var $imgH = $('#myCarouselSlideImage'+$slideNum).height(); //G
          console.log('$imgW ====> '+$imgW);
          console.log('$imgH ====> '+$imgH);
          var $result = ''; 
          $result = ScaleImage($imgW, $imgH, $parentImgW, $parentImgH, true); //H
          console.log('$result.width ====> '+$result.width);
          console.log('$result.height ====> '+$result.height);
          console.log('$result.targetleft ====> '+$result.targetleft);
          console.log('$result.targettop ====> '+$result.targettop);
          $('#myCarouselSlideImage'+$slideNum).animate({ // I
                              width:$result.width+'px',
                              height:$result.height+'px',
                              left:$result.targetleft+'px',
                              top:$result.targettop+'px' },
                                       300);
       });
   });
```

**See it runnig at** https://jsfiddle.net/nd90r1ht/57/ or at https://jsfiddle.net/omarlin25/nd90r1ht/59/